# How to get the index of an item in std::array without using a loop?

Tags: c++11, stdarray

How can I get the index an item in a `std::array` without running any loops?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

std::array<int, 10> some_array = { 89, 56, 78, 96, 4, 34, 77, 2, 48, 3};

unsigned int GetIndexOfValue(unsigned int some_value) {
    // How get the index of some_value here without running a loop?
}

int main() {
    unsigned int some_value = 34;
    std::cout << "The index of value passed is " << GetIndexOfValue(some_value) << std::endl;
}
```

Is it possible to do it using `std::find`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the functionality from the `<algorithm>` header, so you can avoid writing a raw loop, like this:

```
unsigned int GetIndexOfValue(unsigned int some_value) {
    return std::distance(std::begin(some_array),
             std::find(std::begin(some_array), std::end(some_array), some_value));
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qzEhqW).

Answer (score 1):

```
std::find(some_array.begin(), some_array.end(), some_value) - some_array.begin()
```

should do the trick (not tested).

Comment: Yes, `std::find` returns an iterator - that's why I subtract `some_array.begin()` from it, to arrive at an index. You could use `std::distance` instead if you are so inclined.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to do it using std::find?

Yes: with a `std::array` it's possible.

```
std::array<int, 10> some_array = { 89, 56, 78, 96, 4, 34, 77, 2, 48, 3};

auto idx =   std::find(some_array.cbegin(), some_array.cend(), 34)
           - some_array.cbegin();

std::cout << "The index of value passed is " << idx << std::endl;
```

With `std::find()` you get an iterator that, in the case of `std::array` (and `std::vector`) is a random access iterator and support the difference; so you can subtract the `cbegin()` iterator getting the index

But this doesn't mean that you can avoid a loop: the loop is inside `std::find()`.

See also [the answer from cigien](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63219024/6022656) that works also with containers not supporting random access iterators: you can use `std::distance()`.

But, in case of a container supporting a non-random access iterator, I suppose that `std::distance()` can introduce a second loop. So, in this case, I suppose is better if you directly write a single loop.

Comment: @vsoftco - in case of a random access iterator (`std::array` and `std::vector`, at least) is guarantee, as far I know.

Comment: Not 100% sure. It's certainly true that the `Distance` type is `ptrdiff_t`, https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator, but cannot find anywhere an `operator-` for random access iterators.

Comment: @vsoftco - well... I see that now is named "LegacyRandomAccessIterator". I suppose it's to avoid confusion with the new (C++20) `std::random_access_iterator` concept... C++ become more complicated with every passing version.

Comment: @vsoftco - anyway, from [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) you can see that an `std::array` iterator has to be a "LegacyRandomAccessIterator" (before C++20) and from [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/RandomAccessIterator) you can see that must support the difference